# Add config file to Maven packages in Gitlab Package Repository

Tags: java, maven, gitlab-ci

I have a Maven project on Gitlab for which I want to automatize the build.

Building my project creates a **JAR** file, and a **JSON** file and I need to store them in a Gitlab Registry.

Following the documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/index.html#create-maven-packages-with-gitlab-cicd), I managed to build my Project and upload the JAR file in the Package Registry. However, I don't know how to manage my JSON file.

Is there a way to store/link this JSON file to my JAR file in some way in the Registry ?

Here is my build configuration in my `pom.xml`

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <url>${env.CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>gitlab-maven</id>
      <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
      <plugin>
        [plugin building the JSON file]
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <_exportcontents>[my_package]</_exportcontents>
            <Embed-Dependency>*;inline=false;scope=compile</Embed-Dependency>
            <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
            <Embed-Directory>lib</Embed-Directory>
          </instructions>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>bundle</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: You could probably use [GitLab's Generic Packages Repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/generic_packages/) for that.

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks !